# How to display one whole website inside another directly..?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am kind of new to website development. I am curious to know whether it is possible to display someone's website inside my website like displaying w3schools.com inside a stackoverflow.com in a smaller block as a part of the website.

Comment: You can use [iframes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames).

Comment: Somehow I doubt very much that StackOverflow.com would want to embed w3schools

Comment: and one small doubt. Is it legal to include someone's website without their permission..?

Comment: @VasanthHegde - you may find that a lot of sites include headers to prevent them from being framed like this.  It is a security measure to stop people from trivially setting up 'phishing' type sites.

Comment: do one have right to sue if his website being framed..?

Comment: You have a right to sue if your site is framed, whether you'd win in court is another matter, maybe, maybe not

Comment: One should also note that we aren't lawyers - you should address your query to a lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use iframe.

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to close the question if this suits you :)

Comment: and one small doubt. Is it legal to include someone's website without their permission..?

Comment: If the page is not secured I doubt that is illegal do display it in an iframe. If that page is secured then you won't be able to use it in an external iframe :)

Answer (score 2):

An IFrame would be the simplest way to do this.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html

Comment: Where is that message?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>
```

its should be work

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src ="http://www.w3schools.com" width="500px" height="300px">
```